# directory hash instead of the original path

Tags: nginx

This is how I store my projects on the server `dev.anuary.com/mike-gamaroff/2011 10 04 unbreakable-embrace/`, i.e. `server + client name + project data and name`.

The problem is, that some clients started to complain about their names appearing in the URL, when it is visible. Is there a way to get to the URL path using some sort of hash of the original directory path?

That `dev.anuary.com/mike-gamaroff/2011 10 04 unbreakable-embrace/` would become `dev.anuary.com/2989dh42[whatever]098dfsdfsf/`, though, I could still keep the original directory tree?

Answer (score 1):

Create symbolic links on the server?

```
 PROJECT_NAME="$server/$clientName/$projectData $name/"
 ln -s /var/www/vhosts/dev.anuary.com/htdocs/$server/$projectData\ $name /var/www/vhosts/dev.anuary.com/htdocs/mike-gamaroff/`echo $PROJECT_NAME | md5sum`
```

Just a quick guess ...

Then, the site would be available via the normal URL you are speaking about, or via the md5sum URL.

If you want to have this enabled for all projects, you'll need to either manually create them, or do some fun recursion with a shell script down through all the various directories.  The benefit to doing this is that you can update a master file that provides a proper reference between project name and hash .. for quick reference

```
for dir in $(find ./ -type d); do
     # do some fancy symbolic linking if the criteria is right
done
```

Comment: That could work, though, that would require creating a symbolic link for every project, which would be a pain. I am wondering whether there is a more automated way to do it. Though, if no other suggestions come up, this is the answer.

Comment: If you have the energy (maybe another question on this site), create a simple bash script that recursively goes through and creates them for you ... if it already exists, skip.